# WordPress plugin to handle paid access to BuddyPress pages

Tags: wordpress, online-payment, login

I have a private WordPress community with a double check for the new members, to which I want to ask payment features.

It uses three plugins:

- [BuddyPress](https://buddypress.org/) to basically set up the community features
- I let the users log in with the [Facebook Login](https://wpcore.com/plugin/wp-facebook-login) plugin by Damian Logghe
- I use the [BuddyPress Registration Options](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-registration-options/) plugin to moderate/approve new members

**Now I am looking for a plugin to restrict access to the BuddyPress pages and with which they can pay to interact with the content.**
After the login/registration, I tell the logged in user that he has to pay a membership to interact with other members. Do you know of such a WordPress plugin that I can use with the above ones?

I have tried the [Paid Memberships Pro](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/) plugin to restrict some pages, but when I create a fake user and go to the site from incognito mode these pages are still visible to that user.

I am willing to pay for a good solution.